# java.lang.LinkageError:when resolving method "javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory()

Tags: java, websphere, sslsocketfactory, linkageerror

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.getSocketFactory()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@31bff837" of class "org/apache/kafka/common/security/oauthbearer/secured/JaasOptionsUtils" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@b46c41f7" of class "javax/net/ssl/SSLContext" have different types for the method signature
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:484)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:428)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.getSocketFactory()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@31bff837" of class "org/apache/kafka/common/security/oauthbearer/secured/JaasOptionsUtils" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@b46c41f7" of class "javax/net/ssl/SSLContext" have different types for the method signature
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.JaasOptionsUtils.createSSLSocketFactory(JaasOptionsUtils.java:77)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.AccessTokenRetrieverFactory.create(AccessTokenRetrieverFactory.java:69)
at org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler.configure(OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler.java:186)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:151)
... 24 more

This error comes up after adding the dependency,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

The application is using java 8 and deployed on websphere server.
Theapplication is also having httpclient dependency as well
Does anybody knows what should I do? Or what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.